# Java: How to export data (db, query or table contents) to Excel?

Tags: java, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I would like to know how to export the contents of a table or the data from a query to an Excel file. Also wich is the file extension  that is better to export to, xls or csv?

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit: What i want is the user to to be able to export the contents of a JTable -containing the results from a query- to an Excel compatible file, by pressing a button.

I don't know what is the best way to do it? I found various ways but i'm not sure which one to follow. Is it possible to generate a JasperReport then export tha same data to excel?

---

Edit2:Ok so i decided to export to .csv like most of you suggest. My last question is which one is better to use, opecsv or [javacsv](http://www.csvreader.com/java_csv_samples.php)? Both seem really easy to use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exporting to csv is easier - and could be done manually in a pinch depending on the data (Each new row is a new line, and cell values are seperated by a comma) - There are open source libraries available for this (http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/), and the code for copying a resultset to your output should be trivial

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely need Excel, use the Apache POI library.

Comment: I am making this app as an assignment and the professor said that it must be able to export to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create text file (csv) and write the result of database.

```
PrintWriter out
   = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("foo.csv")));

while(rs.next())
{
  out.println(String.format("%s,%s,%s",rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3));
}
```

Comment: I agree, this is a totally valid solution and takes advantage of the simplicity of csv formats!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers already given, I would like to say that I would prefer CSV.

CSV is application-agnostic and you could manipulate the data later on with any other language/program (Python, R, Java, Excel, etc).

Answer (score -1):

I had good success with jXLS:
 http://jxls.sourceforge.net/

this lets you use JSP-like tags in a native Excel template with all the formatting etc.  You pass data to substitute into that Excel template from Java API calls, via a Map structure (analogous to request scope vars.)

This is a good lighter-weight alternative to JasperReports if you just want formatted Excel output.